# Stripe Intent Confirm with Delphi FMX

Tags: rest, delphi, stripe-payments, firemonkey

I have an FMX app written in Delphi 10.3. I am using REST components to communicate to the APIs.  First, I request a `payment_intents` from my backend, `api.stripe.com`.   This returns a `client_secret`.

Next, I want to confirm this intent at Stripe via `/v1/payment_intents/'+GlobalData.bookings[0].ClientSecretpi+'/confirm`

Every time I try, it will give an error about sending CC info. Which I understand.  But my question is, how do I then complete this intent?  On the web, I have `stripe.js`, and can use elements to display the fields for CC, but in Delphi I cannot do that.

Here is my current code:

```pascal
// seperate month and year
delimiterPos := Pos('/', editExpires.Text);
monthStr := copy(editExpires.text, 1, delimiterPOS - 1);
yearStr := copy(editExpires.text, delimiterpos +1, length(editExpires.text) - delimiterPos);

//Remove Secret from this to get the pi_ order number
Globaldata.bookings[0].clientSecretPi := RemoveSecret(GlobalData.bookings[0].clientSecret);

RESTClient := TRESTClient.Create('https://api.stripe.com');
RESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
RESTResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);

RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('Authorization', 'bearer '+GlobalData.bookings[0].Key).Options := [poDoNotEncode];
RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('client_secret', GlobalData.bookings[0].clientSecret).Options := [poDoNotEncode];
RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
RestRequest.params.AddItem('return_url','https://example.com',pkQUERY);
RestRequest.params.additem('payment_method_data[type]','card',pkQUERY);
RestRequest.params.additem('payment_method_data[card][number]',CreditCardNumber,pkQUERY);
RestRequest.params.addItem('payment_method_data[card][cvc]',SecurityCode,pkQUERY);
RestRequest.params.addItem('payment_method_data[card][exp_year]',yearStr,pkQUERY);
RestRequest.params.addItem('payment_method_data[card][exp_month]',monthStr,PKQUERY);
RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
RESTRequest.Resource := '/v1/payment_intents/'+GlobalData.bookings[0].ClientSecretpi+'/confirm'; // Endpoint for creating tokens

RESTRequest.Client := RESTClient;
RESTRequest.Response := RESTResponse;

RESTRequest.Execute;
ResponseContent := RESTResponse.Content;

JsonResponse := TJSONObject.parseJSONValue(RESTResponse.Content) as TJSONObject;
Contentstring := RESTResponse.Content;
```

Here is the response message:

```json
"error": {
    "message": "Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see https://stripe.com/docs/testing. To enable raw card data APIs in test mode, see https://support.stripe.com/questions/enabling-access-to-raw-card-data-apis.",
```

Comment: Due to [PCI compliance](https://support.stripe.com/questions/enabling-access-to-raw-card-data-apis), raw card information can only be processed if you complete SAQ-D or a PCI level 1 merchant. Without any of them, you can't collect the raw card information. Unfortunately, Stripe doesn't support card information collection on Delphi. StripeJS or SDK is only supported on the [browsers](https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/supported_browsers), iOS and Android.

Comment: Only way I could come up with was to use stripe Checkout and embed the final Payment Link URL into an Edge browser with TMS Component.  This seems to work and keeps me PCI free.   Some reason the TWebBrowser component would not handle it.